# Vue.js 3 - "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a website in Vue 3 with all the routes stored in `routes.json`. (I did this so I have one place to update all of the data that will change over time.) But when I try to `eval()` the lazy-load functions for my `views`, I get the error "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"." in the console. Below is `router/index.js`:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from '../../data/routes.json'

let evalRoutes = []
for (let i = 0; i < routes.routes.length; i++)
  evalRoutes[i] = routes.routes[i]

for (let i = 0; i < evalRoutes.length; i++)
  evalRoutes[i].component = eval(evalRoutes[i].component)
console.log(evalRoutes)

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: evalRoutes,
})

export default router
```

And below is `routes.json`:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "name": "Home",
      "component": "() => import('../views/Home')"
    },
    {
      "path": "/about",
      "name": "About",
      "component": "() => import('../views/About')"
    },
    {
      "path": "/contact",
      "name": "Contact",
      "component": "() => import('../views/Contact')"
    },
    {
      "path": "/policy",
      "name": "Policy",
      "component": "() => import('../views/Policy')"
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't seen anyone do this before, so if you know a solution please leave it down below :)

SETUP:
I have Vue 3, Babel, Router with history mode and SASS, nothing else.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I (the question asker) have figured it out! To do such things, we need to set `"component"` to null. Then, in `index`, instead of evaluating each string import, we set each component to the import with the name.

Comment: would you add some details? I have the same problem

Comment: Some code samples please

Comment: Then you defeat the purpose of using lazy loading here, this is clear a server misconfig, but not sure which one to provide a better reference

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because your server does not support history mode. History mode relies on the server rewrite to pass the routes to index.html file.

You will need to provide more information regarding your setup and your Apache or nginx configuration. Here is the sample setups from the docs: [example-server-configurations](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Alternatively, you can use the hashbang mode by replacing `createWebHistory` with `createWebHashHistory`. This method relies on the `#` character in the route, which will process all routes through the index.html page without server rewrites.

Comment: My server does support history mode actually...I will update my question whoops